# How can we add option to upload/search for dataset in database and local machine in rshiny based on my simple codes?

Tags: r, shiny, rshiny

On my Ui.R

---

fluidPage(

```
    titlePanel("Data Browser"),
    sidebarLayout(
     
      sidebarPanel(
        width = 12,
        # radioButtons("filetype", "Select file type",choices=c("csv file","xlsx file", "xls file")),
        fileInput("file","Choose file to upload..",accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv",".xlsx",".xls"))
        
      ),
      mainPanel(
        width = 12,
        uiOutput("data_browsing")
      )
    )
    
  ) #end of fluid row #2
```

---

server.R

```
 data <- eventReactive(input$file, {
    extension <- tools::file_ext(input$file$name)
    filepath <- input$file$datapath
    switch(extension,
           csv = read.csv(filepath),
           xls = readxl::read_xls(filepath),
           xlsx = readxl::read_xlsx(filepath)
    )
  })
  output$about_file<-renderTable({
    summary(input$file)  #input$file1
  })
  output$display <- renderDataTable({
    dataset = data()},
    10,
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
  output$data_browsing<-renderUI({
    if(is.null(data())){
    }else if(length(data())==1){
      h4(br(),br(),"Mismatch in formats of file selected and uploaded!",style = "color:red")
    }else{
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Data Browse",dataTableOutput("display"))
      ) }})
```

---

So I want to add an option to let the user browse like file_input on local machine and database, and let the dataset to go through my other codes for visualization.

Comment: What do you mean by "local machine"? Doesn't `fileInput` browse on the local machine? And what is your database?

Comment: I mean not a database, sorry it more from a server itself. So let's say i have a data warehouse where all my datasets there, how can i let the user can pick from the server or from local machine like the code above.